# Python: Convert "string" without any conversion to binary

Tags: python, string, binary, type-conversion

My program connects to a Firebird database (using firebirdsql), where a "BLOB" of type string is sometimes used to store binary data. I do not have influence on the database structure and cannot change that.
If I print a row of a table it can look this:

`print(x)`

`(-1, 'ÿÿÿÿ\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00ð¿\x10\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01ÿ¯\x00\x00')`

Using `print(x[1])` it becomes:

`ÿÿÿÿð¿ÿ¯`

For some reason all the invalid UTF-8 has disappeared.

What I need is the original binary data, Python always thinks of it as UTF-8, is there any way to relabel the string to binary without converting any data? The data is obviously there, as the first print shows.

I tried `encode('utf-8')` and `encode('latin1')`, but that will modify the data or fail. I need the original unmodified data.

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(x[1]))`?

Comment: when printing, the non-printable characters are, well, not printed

Comment: Is `x[1].encode('ascii')` what you want?

Comment: x[1] is the original binary data. what else do you need from it?

Comment: The lack of `b` prefix to the string indicates that it's not a BINARY blob, but rather TEXT blob, as [there are two blob types](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-blob.html).  Perhaps try modifying your query e.g [`cast(yourfield as BLOB SUB_TYPE BINARY)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66177799), as there was implicit conversion to `str` rather than leaving the original data as `bytes`. Moreover, using `print` will generally not do what you want when it comes to binary data.  Also, it would be useful to include the expected raw binary in terms hex in the question itself.

Comment: This doesn't look like text, because of all those `\x00` bytes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795042/how-to-cast-a-string-to-bytes-without-encoding for how to convert the string to a byte string without encoding.

Comment: Also, Python does not "think of it as UTF-8", `str` by definition is a sequence of _unicode codepoints_, UTF-8 is a *codec* that may be used to convert _unicode codepoints_ to/from _bytes_, i.e. it could have been used to convert from the original bytes had the original bytes started with `c3 bf x3 c3 bf x3`; likewise latin1 is a codec and could have turned that `str` to/from bytes that starts with `ff ff ff ff 01 00` - this is why you should include the expected raw bytes as hexadecimal to better help determine what/where might have gone wrong and what encoding was (mis)used.

Comment: The point is, that it is binary data that is misclassified as string. It is interpreted as UTF-8, but it isn't. How to tell Python this is not a string, but a byte sequence, please treat this string as byte sequence. `print(type(x[1]))` is `<class 'str'>`.
I tried casting, but it results in the same problem: I get a byte sequence that starts with `c3 bf x3 c3 bf x3` rather than `ff ff ff ff`. I assume now Firebird is doing the wrong conversion

Comment: Found the solution, it is done even wronger than I thought: The original binary data is interpreted as a cp1252 string and converted to UTF-8 for storing in the database. So converting the UTF-8 string to cp1252 binary solves the issue...

Comment: Yeah, that's been my experience when inheriting legacy systems, as I said you need to find the correct **codec**, and please stop perpetuating further wrongness by calling what you had a UTF-8 string (this is very much NOT a thing), what you have is unicode codepoints (Python 3 `str` represents that) and you need to turn it back into binary data through the original codec that made it into unicode codepoints, in your case it is cp1252.  UTF-8 typically only apply to bytes, where bytes that represents unicode codepoints might be encoded using the UTF-8 encoding (which is _not_ a `str`).